# Matching comma regex works but negation does not

Tags: python, regex, regex-negation

I've got this model class:

```
class ItemTag(models.Model):

  name_regex = re.compile(r'[^,]')
  name = models.CharField('Tag Name', max_length = 20, unique = True,
                          validators=[RegexValidator(regex=name_regex)] )
  class Meta:
    ordering = ['name']
```

I need to use the validator to reject strings with commas in them.  I expected re.compile(r'[^,]') to do this but it's not.

When I change it to re.compile(r'[,]') it requires the comma, which is what I expected, but the negation of the character class doesn't seem to work as expected and I haven't been able to find any explanation in the documentation.

I use these applications:

Python 2.6.5
Django 1.4.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[^,]` means "one character, any character except a `,`".

So your regex was checking that there was at least one non-comma character.

You can use this instead to ensure *only* non-comma characters are in your string:

```
^[^,]+$
```

`^$` are anchors matching the beginning and end of the string respectively.

Comment: That's perfect.  I should have known to use the + but I don't think I would have thought about boxing it in with ^$
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should use the following regex:

```
name_regex = re.compile(r'^[^,]*$')
```

This checks the **whole string** to ensure that none of the characters are a `,`

Answer (score 0):

Use negative lookahead `(?!.*[,])`

```
class ItemTag(models.Model):

  name_regex = re.compile("^(?!.*[,]).*$")
  name = models.CharField('Tag Name', max_length = 20, unique = True,
                          validators=[RegexValidator(regex=name_regex)] )
  class Meta:
    ordering = ['name']
```

Comment: Why the character class? Also I don't think OP knows what's a negative look ahead, nor the name of the pattern to look it up.